# Visual Studio 2012 can not check in because: could not find file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I'm trying to check in my files in Visual Studio 2012, there are lots of files which I have not in my solution and it says:

```
Could not find file 'D:\Workspaces\Mehran\Portal\Main\Source\Portal\Source\Carane.Portal.Shell.Web\Controllers\TodoController.cs'.
```

And the check in fails.

When I change the `Show All` in the `Included Changes` to `Custom Filter` I can find them and undo them.
But why are they creating and not showing in my solution.

What's the meaning of the `Including Changes (234 of 461)? What's the other than 234 files that aren't shown in the changes list?

Comment: "it says" - who is "it"? VS inself or some plugin?

Comment: @Micha thanks, it really helps, but what about some files which are in the list but doesn't exist in the code or anywhere in the solution structure.

Comment: I'm little bit confused. What have I said which helps you? I only want to know what you mean with "it" in your first sentence.